# Can I get upload path at runtime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I need to get upload path of my uploaded files via [jquery-file-uploader](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/).

```
$('.new_plotphoto').fileupload({
    done: function (e, data) {
        var filess = data.files[0];
        var filename = filess.name;
        var filepath = filess.filepath;
        console.log(filename); // this shows filename
        console.log(filepath); // this shows undefined
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Path of uploading file is a secure feature. From [W3C File API docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#file-attrs) about file name:

> The name of the file; on getting, this must return the name of the
>   file as a string. There are numerous file name variations on different
>   systems; this is merely the name of the file, **without path
>   information**.

File path will be enabled only then you upload directory:

```html
<input type=file multiple directory webkitdirectory onchange="console.log(this.files)">
```

In this case `webkitRelativePath`(for WebKit browsers) field of file object will be not empty. But it will show path only inside uploaded directory.

Also note that `iOS` browsers then uploading images always have this file name: `image.jpg` and no info about path.